# can I skip deps with CPANPLUS?

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm having some dependency issues with some packages. I have to use CPANPLUS (cpan & cpanm are not options) is there any way I can skip dependencies when installing a package? `--force` seems to install all dependencies (even if they're already installed and is leading to a circular dep in this case) and `--skiptest` just skips tests.

Comment: If the dependencies are already installed, what is the issue you're encountering that creates a circular dependencies?

Comment: @HerbN I'll quote myself "--force installs all dependencies even if they're already installed" when 2 packages depend on each other --force will continue to install the deps back and forth.... it was very annoying, I manually resolved the problem which really doesn't resolve this question.

Answer (score -1):

You always could just download the .deb file (or .rpm/.tgz, depending on your distro) and just extract it and extract the data.tgz (in .deb files, at least) to /. Of course, this is rather ugly as the package isn't tracked and therefore not very easily removed.

Comment: the package isn't tracked normally if you use cpanplus (at least by your package manager). The reason I /have/ to use cpanplus is that there's an extension which allows packages to be installed with my package manager. btw not all 20k+ cpan modules are packaged by debian. I don't use a .deb or .rpm distro, and I know how to package stuff for my distro.

Comment: downmodded because it doesn't answer the question asked.